# How to quickly fill a rectangle with colors of different proportions?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw

I want to draw a picture as shown below. There are many rectangles. Each rectangle can be filled with a 1/N (N=1-8) ratio of colors.

I've taken the dumbest approach before. That is, I draw a rectangle of the corresponding size, and then cover it. For example if I want to fill 1/2 of the color. I covered it with a rectangle that is only half the area. But is there any way to do it quickly?
I want to draw using Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Grid and Snap to Grid. Then create one filled rectangle, say a 4x8. Then draw a square on top (8x8) with a stroke and no fill, and type a number on top, and set the text to Align Centre.

Then select everything, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click and drag to make as many duplicates as you need. Then you can adjust the fill by clicking and dragging an edge, and finally retype the numbers.

[image]

Another possibility instead of separate shapes would be to make a square and fill it with a gradient with a sharp transition, then you could simply move the gradient up or down as required. However, using this method the gradient will not snap to the grid, and positioning it would be more manual and require you to zoom in to get it accurate.

[image]